# In which version of Windows did each VC++ re-distributable become standard?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

My understanding is that the VC++ redists are essentially updates to some core Windows files, and that over time MS "catches up" by incorporating past versions into new versions/updates to Windows. For instance I'd probably expect anything built with VC++ 2005 wouldn't need me to install the redist on target PCs these days.

Can anyone provide definitive reference for which versions of Windows include which VC++ redist versions?

Also, is the redist approach something MS still employ in the newest versions of VC++ e.g. 2012 and later?

Comment: No, the MSVC redistables do *not* update "core Windows files".  They only contain the DLLs that a C or C++ program needs and are not included in the Windows installer.  And no, hoping that you don't have to deploy them is hoping that somebody else did the job for you.  You are guaranteed to encounter a user's machine where that did not happen.  Particularly for the VS2005 version of them, nine years is a long time ago.  There is no "redist approach", Microsoft simply makes a pre-cooked installer available to help users that need to deal with a programmer that didn't create his own installer.

Comment: So newer versions of Windows don't bundle in older redists? e.g. an application built with VC++ 2005 still has to install the 2005 redist on a W7/8 PC?

Comment: And yes they _do_ update core Windows components. From MS "This package installs runtime components of C Runtime (CRT), Standard C++, ATL, MFC" - my understanding is the redist includes newer versions of MFC, etc, which users may not yet have from standard Windows install. Unless you're disputing the "core" part only?

Comment: None of the files distributed with modern versions of Visual Studio are updates to files that ship with Windows.  Windows does ship with a C runtime, which is used internally and (for reasons of backwards compatibility) by applications built with Visual Studio 6 or earlier versions.  Later versions of Visual Studio each have their own runtime, none of which are shipped with Windows.

Comment: Do you have a source @HarryJohnston? That's the answer I needed but it seems crazy newer versions of windows don't incorporate the redist from older VC++ versions!

Comment: @John: well, I guess MS don't want to get sued for giving their compiler an advantage over third-party compilers.  Or perhaps they just wanted to avoid the complexity of having multiple distributions of each runtime.  Sorry, I don't know that this is documented anywhere - MS don't generally write documentation about things that they *don't* do. :-) Might be a blog post somewhere I suppose.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx

Answer (score 1):

None of the files distributed with modern versions of Visual Studio are updates to files that ship with Windows.

Windows does ship with a C runtime, which is used internally and (for reasons of backwards compatibility) by applications built with Visual Studio 6 or earlier versions. Later versions of Visual Studio each have their own runtime, none of which are shipped with Windows.